# Collision detection - response between a moving sphere and a circular cylinder

Tags: 3d, geometry, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm implementing a simple game that encorporates 3d logic. What is the procedure or/and the relative equations in order to detect if a moving sphere collides with a cylinder? My cylinder is static right circular and aligned to z axis. I read that cylinder's equation in this case is (x - a)² + (z - b)² = r², where

(a, b): center of cylinder
r: radius of cylinder

How can I use it to find if the two objects intersect and, additionally, how can I apply the corresponding response of the ball?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a cylinder to sphere test can be simplified to a point to line segment test where:

1. the line segment represents the line running through the center of
   the cylinder from end to end **and** the end points are known.
2. The point represents the centerPoint of the sphere.
3. The test finds a point on the line segment that is closest to centerPoint
   and simply measures the distance between points and if it is less
   than sphere radius + cyl radius, it is colliding.

The compromise with this is that it makes it effectively a sphere to capsule test rather than sphere to cylinder. If you can live with this compromise, here's some pseudo code.

```
vector cylCenterVector = endPoint2 - endpoint1;
float distanceFactorFromEP1 = Dot(sphereCenter - endPoint1) / Dot(cylCenterVector , cylCenterVector );
if(distanceFactorFromEP1 < 0) distanceFactorFromEP1 = 0;// clamp to endpoints if neccesary
if(distanceFactorFromEP1 > 1) distanceFactorFromEP1 = 1;
vector closestPoint = endPoint1 + (cylCenterVector * distanceFactorFromEP1);

vector collisionVector = sphereCenter - closestPoint;
float distance = collisionVector.Length();
vector collisionNormal = collisionVector / distance;

if(distance < sphereRadius + cylRadius)
{
  //collision occurred. use collisionNormal to reflect sphere off cyl

  float factor = Dot(velocity, collisionNormal);

  velocity = velocity - (2 * factor * collisionNormal);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a capsule ? Do you mean that the top and bottom of the cylinder would have half a sphere on them ?

Comment: just pointing out a mistake, i believe there should be a cylCenterVector in the first dot product: Dot(sphereCenter - endPoint1,cylCenterVector) / Dot(cylCenterVector , cylCenterVector )